# css layout is strange

Tags: html, css

I am making a website, let me show the code first:

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: "helvetica neue",arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        background-color: #edece9;
    }
    .card {
        width: 250px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 11px;
    }
    .footer {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .body {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .body p {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .screen-shot {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="body">
    <img src="" class="screen-shot">
</div>
<div class="footer" style="background-color: #4caf50;">
    <p>
        <a title="查看详情" style="cursor: pointer; color:white">项目名称一</a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Now let me tell you the bug, the 'padding' property of the class 'body' is 10px before, and the web looks like this:

**previous page:**
[image]

The card type boxes layout is nothing wrong, that is what I want, but it has the white padding around the pictures, it doesn't look well, so I remove the 'padding' property of the class 'body', as I wish, the pictures haven't the white padding. But another problem arises, some of the blank areas appeared:

**the wrong page:**
[image]

I tried the 'padding' in 1,2,3 px, it also wrong, the bug is so strange. I want to make the picture1's box type layout and the pictures haven't the padding.I don't know how to describe the problem, so I post the code and the screenshot, they are the best description.

Comment: Why not use flexbox? It would solve many issues for you and allow you to easily make your site responsive

Comment: can you put this into a jsfiddle so we can better figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the image height. Some of the images seem to have a single pixel more in height than the others, which will affect the floated images on the next line. The padding worked because the images were being scaled down (you've set an explicit width on `.card`) and due to that scaling did not have the extra pixel in height.

[image: Screenshot]

You can do a few things to fix that, such as setting a `height` on the images, or use a solution as @ctwheels suggested (possibly flexbox).

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .card {
        width: 200px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 11px;
        float: left;
    }
    .footer {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .body  {
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .body p {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .screen-shot {
        width: 100%;
        padding:0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="card">
    <div class="body">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"     class="screen-shot">
   </div>
 <div class="footer" style="background-color: #4caf50;">
    <p>
        <a title="查看详情" style="cursor: pointer; color:white">项目名一         </a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="body">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7591/16992834140_99815ee4ac_m.jpg"     class="screen-shot">
   </div>
 <div class="footer" style="background-color: #4caf50;">
    <p>
        <a title="查看详情" style="cursor: pointer; color:white">项目名一         </a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="body">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"     class="screen-shot">
   </div>
 <div class="footer" style="background-color: #4caf50;">
    <p>
        <a title="查看详情" style="cursor: pointer; color:white">项目名一         </a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="body">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7591/16992834140_99815ee4ac_m.jpg"     class="screen-shot">
   </div>
 <div class="footer" style="background-color: #4caf50;">
    <p>
        <a title="查看详情" style="cursor: pointer; color:white">项目名一         </a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="body">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"     class="screen-shot">
   </div>
 <div class="footer" style="background-color: #4caf50;">
    <p>
        <a title="查看详情" style="cursor: pointer; color:white">项目名一         </a>
    </p>
</div>
</div><div class="card">
    <div class="body">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"     class="screen-shot">
   </div>
 <div class="footer" style="background-color: #4caf50;">
    <p>
        <a title="查看详情" style="cursor: pointer; color:white">项目名一         </a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Try setting static height for the card. The different image height casing the issue